# How to type a mutation in typescript + apollo

Tags: typescript, apollo, react-apollo

given I have a mutation that looks like this.

```
mutation SignInMutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
  signIn(input: {email: $email, password: $password}) {
    token {
      accessToken
      accessTokenExpiresOn
    }
  }
}
```

how would I use the type the graphql function in `react-apollo` to then add a `signIn` method to a class?

e.g.

```
import SignInMutation from '~/mutations/SignInMutation.gql`
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'

@graphql(SignInMutation, {
  props: ({ mutate }) => ({
    signIn: (variables) => mutate({variables})
  })
})
class SignInPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
  }
  render() {
   <form>
     ...
     <button onClick={() => this.props.signIn(this.state)}>
     </button>
   </form>
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand clearly but try @graphql(SignInMutation, {name: 'signIn'}) and then you can use SignInMutation as signIn method from props. In class define eg. handleSignIn and call this.props.signIn with proper variables. Or maybe you want to avoid creating handleSignIn method?

Comment: @magnat, doing both the implementation that I did or the one you suggested results in the decorator being improperly typed. I get an error saying `Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  Type 'ComponentClass<SignInProps>' is not assignable to type 'typeof SignInPage'.
    Type 'Component<SignInProps, ComponentState>' is not assignable to type 'SignInPage'.
      Property 'handleSubmit' is missing in type 'Component<SignInProps, ComponentState>'.`

Answer (score 1):

There is a small library and a CLI to generate react-apollo components using your queries and mutations inside GraphQL files in your project. So, you can use them easily by importing generated file like;

```
import { YourQuery } from './generated';

<YourQuery.Component>
...
</YourQuery.Component>
```

You can try it here: https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator

And there is a blog post here;
https://medium.com/the-guild/graphql-code-generator-for-typescript-react-apollo-7b225672588f